# Access violation in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, exception, matrix

I got the following code which is supposed to correctly acess the matrix positions, however I'm always getting this access violation...

```
var
tabla : array of array of string;

....
implementation

SetLength(tabla, minterms.Count+1, minterms_essentials.Count+1);

for i := 0 to minterms.Count-1 do
begin
  tabla[i+2,1] := minterms[i];
end;

for i := 0 to minterms_essentials.Count-1 do
begin
  tabla[1, i+2] := minterms_essentials[i];
end;

end
```

Basically, I'm generating a table and in the loop I'm trying to fill the column tags and the row tags in second loop. As long as I know, arrays start in 1.

`tabla[1][1]` would an unoccupied index, that's why I'm ain't *touching it*.

**Why the access violation?**

Comment: A better question is why you have range checking disabled.

Comment: Does the above code even compile? It doesn't look like full real code...

Comment: @JerryDodge: It's not "full real code," but it's enough to show where the problem is.

Comment: I mean I know "fake code" is typically acceptable, but when it's a discombobulated mess of code in an attempt to make a sample unit, that just points out to me that the OP didn't really try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RobKennedy How can I set range checking on?

Comment: It's in your project's compiler options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi, dynamic arrays (any array that you can call SetLength on, as opposed to declaring its bounds at compile time like `array[1..5] of integer`) are indexed starting from 0, not from 1.  So by treating your array as if it used 1-based indexing instead of 0-based indexing, you're overflowing the bounds of the array and trying to write to memory that's not allocated to you, which can cause an access violation.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic arrays always start at `0`.

Because of

```
SetLength(tabla, minterms.Count+1, minterms_essentials.Count+1);
```

the highest possible *first* index of `tabla` is `minterms.Count`.

Now, think about

```
for i := 0 to minterms.Count-1 do
begin
  tabla[i+2,1] := minterms[i];
```

When `i` is `minterms.Count-1`, `i+2` is `minterms.Count+1`. Hence, you try to access `tabla[minterms.Count+1]`. But this doesn't exist, because, as we saw, the maximum possible first index of `tabla` is `minterms.Count`.

Hence you try to access something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start at zero and the max. index is Count-1

Therefore, if minterms.Count equals three, setlength(..., 4) ==> Index between 0 and 3.

```
for i := 0 to minterms.Count-1 do
```

will do just fine, but change i+2 into i in the loops body.