# finding the max value in a database with delphi

Tags: arrays, database, delphi, delphi-2010

I am working with Delphi 2010. I have a Microsoft Access database called tblUserInfo, in it there is a field called NUMOFREPORTS, containing 11 numbers. I need to search through the data items and find the maximum number and store it in a variable.
My plan was to assign the values in the database to an array of integers and then sort through the array to find the maximum.

This is what I have so far:

```
i:=1;
while NOT tblUserInfo.eof do
begin
  arrNumOfReps[i]:= tblUserInfo['NUMOFREPORTS'];
  tblUserInfo.Next;
  INC(i);
end;

NumOfReps:= arrNumOfReps[1];
for I := 1 to length(arrNumOfReps) do
begin
  if arrNumOfReps[i] > NumOfReps then
  begin
    NumOfReps:= arrNumOfReps[i];
  end;
  showmessage(inttostr(NumOfReps));
end;
```

When I run the program it does not work and breaks at `NumOfReps:= arrNumOfReps[1];` and I get an error that says "Access violation".

Does anyone have any corrections to my code or alternative solutions?
Thanks

Comment: You're going about this completely the wrong way.  You should be using a Select Max(<columnname.) SQL query agains your table, which is easy to do in Delphi.

Comment: As @MartynA pointed out, let the database do the work.  And read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308246/access-violation-in-delphi, look at Mason Wheeler's answer.

Comment: Why do this on the slowest way possible ? Just do `select max(NUMOFREPORTS) from tblUserInfo` and your done. Take @MartynA 's advice

Comment: I have a feeling `select count(NUMOFREPORTS) from tblUserInfo` is more-so what you need. What if you had a gap where a historical record was removed? The `MAX` has nothing to do with the `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out by MartynA in the comments you should let database to find you the maximum value rather than retrieving all the values first and then search for the maximum value by yourself. Why?

1. In your case you claim that you only have 11 values in this field so retrieving that data from database wouldn't be difficult. But what if you would have one million values there. Retrieving 1M values from database can be quite taxing on the database and would also consume significant amount of memory on your client computer if you store these values in an array for further processing (finding maximum value).
2. Database would surely be able to find the maximum value much faster than you since it can easily split this task between multiple cores. Not to mention the fact that if that specific field is indexed the database most likely already has the maximum value stored as one of the index values in which case database could return the maximum value instantly. And even if the maximum value isn't directly stored as one of the index values database would only have to check part of the records instead of checking each and every one.

And if for some special reason you really can't use database built-in `Select Max` function (perhaps value isn't stored as numeric value but as special string and the maximum value is determined by some part in the middle of the string) and have to really find the max value by yourself don't bother storing all of the values into an array. Instead do the needed comparison for finding the max value directly while retrieving records from database. Perhaps something like this where I just modified your loop for retrieving records from the database:

```
while NOT tblUserInfo.eof do
begin
  if tblUserInfo['NUMOFREPORTS'] > NumOfReps then
  begin
    NumOfReps:= tblUserInfo['NUMOFREPORTS'];
  end;
  tblUserInfo.Next;
end;
```

Comment: I've upvoted this because of your good explanation of the issues, but I think you should improve your answer by  not using the ['FieldName'] construct in a loop, especially twice per iteration.  Better to capture the field's indentity in a local TField variable before starting the loop and do the reads against that.

Comment: @MartynA My intention with my answer was to make it easily understandable. But I totally agree with your proposed optimization of the code example.

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare your array? Based on the way you work with it, it should probably be declared like this:

```
var
  ArrNumOfReps: array[1..12] of Integer;
```

But that's limited, since the program only supports a maximum of 11 values. Rather use a dynamic array

```
var
  ArrNumOfReps: array of Integer;

i:=0;
while NOT tblUserInfo.eof do
begin
  SetLength(ArrNumOfReps, Length(ArrNumOfReps) + 1);
  arrNumOfReps[i]:= tblUserInfo.FieldByName('NUMOFREPORTS').AsInteger;
  tblUserInfo.Next;
  INC(i);
end;
```

This will allow the program to work with a variable number of reps.

Comment: Seriously? Calling SetLength each time around a loop which is going to be executed an indeterminate, possibly huge, number ot times? In any case not a good idea to encourage the OP to persist in the folly of using this approach

Comment: @MartynA Agreed. I was answering OP's question specifically, not trying to give him a tutorial how to write better code.

Comment: @nolaspeaker The problem with that is that OP will not learn and will continue to return here and ask poor questions.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge I'll give him a little more credit than that.